# Error with AbsoluteLayout building project with Maven

Tags: java, maven

```
The POM for unknown.binary:AbsoluteLayout:jar:SNAPSHOT is missing, no 
dependency information available
```

I have this problem with my Java Project, any idea?

Comment: Can you provide more data? like the pom and what you are trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to do a Thread with sound and one interface.

Comment: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (default-cli) on project HilosConJfugue: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

Comment: Can you share your pom and the. Ommand you are running?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be the same question as in [Maven - AbsoluteLayout dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42909316/maven-absolutelayout-dependency).

Adding this to your POM should help:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>netbeans</id>
        <name>Netbeans rep</name>
        <url>http://bits.netbeans.org/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

(Also, try googling yourself next time.)